# Adonis controller doesn't store information to DB

Tags: mysql, adonis.js

I am writing a page where the user should put some information in two text areas, and this text data should write into DB. The row in DB creates with `NULL` in these two areas and `DateTime` is written there.

So in my database I have `id|usuario_nombre|file_nombre|created_at| updated_at`

and `usuario_nombre|file_nombre` have `NULL`, and others have information.

Can you help, please?

**Controller :**

```js
'use strict'

const Upload = use('App/Models/Upload')


class UploadController {
    async index({ view }) 
    {
        const uploads = await Upload.all();
        return view.render('/', {
            uploads: uploads.toJSON()
        })
    }
    async create({ view }) 
    {
        return view.render('/upload');
    }

    async store({ request, response }) 
    {
        const upload = new Upload();
        upload.usuario_nombre = request.input('usuario_nombre');
        upload.file_nombre = request.input('profilefile');
        upload.save();
        response.redirect('/');
    }
}

module.exports = UploadController
```

**Form with inputs :**

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{ csrfField() }}
   <input type="text" id="usuario_nombre"  name="usuario_nombre"/>
   <input type="text" name="profilefile" id="profilefile"/>
   <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

**Routes :**

```js
Route.get('/upload/create', 'UploadController.create')
Route.get('/upload', 'UploadController.store')
    
Route.get('/upload/create', 'UploadController.create')
Route.get('/upload', 'UploadController.store')
```

**Migration :**

```js
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class UploadsSchema extends Schema {
    up() {
        this.create('uploads', (table) => {
            table.increments()
            table.string('usuario_nombre')
            table.string('file_nombre')
            table.timestamps()
        })
    }
    down() {
        this.drop('uploads')
    }
}
module.exports = UploadsSchema
```

Comment: Please read this document to improve you question : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you add `console.info()` to show `request` values from `store` controller. Can you add a `await` operator before `upload.save();` -> `await upload.save();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `await upload.save();` because save() is a async operation